# Trying to use appsetting in script tag's path element

Tags: c#, appsettings, script-tag

Trying to do this... in a asp.net aspx page, trying to make an app someone else wrote driven from config, instead of releasing new code just to use new content

```
<script src="<%$AppSettings:CurrentSecurityTestYear%>/loadflash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

is there a way to do it?

I get this error

> Server Error in '/GLS' Application.
>
> Parser Error    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Literal expressions like
>   '<%$AppSettings:CurrentSecurityTestYear%>' are not allowed. Use
>   " /> instead.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 24:      Line 25:      Line 26:     /loadflash.js"
>   type="text/javascript">    Line 27:  Line 28:
>
> Source File:  /GLS/Main/Flash.aspx    Line:  26

An asp string literal doesn't work, nor does

```
<%=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CurrentSecurityTestYear"]%>
```

Which is not allowed in server tags

Comment: Thanks @Jasen that was a bone headed mistake.

Comment: What kind of app is this? Have you tried it?

Comment: I added more info to make it more explicit for folks who didn't' grock